# Node.js - Connect version incompatible

Tags: node.js

My connect version installed on the machine is 2.3.4. When i install packages like node-inspector, mongoose etc it says my connect version should be between 1.8 to 1.9 and aborts.

Should i uninstall my connect and install older version ?

Error logs:

```
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: connect@'>=1.8.5- <1.9.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.5.5","0.5.6","0.5.7","0.5.8","0.5.9","0.5.10","1.0.0","1.0.1","2.2.2","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","1.9.1","2.3.4"]
```

Full Logs:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-inspector
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: connect@'>=1.8.5- <1.9.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.5.5","0.5.6","0.5.7","0.5.8","0.5.9","0.5.10","1.0.0","1.0.1","2.2.2","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","1.9.1","2.3.4","2.3.5"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:506:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:452:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:427:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:419:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:230:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR!  [Error: No compatible version found: connect@'>=1.8.5- <1.9.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.5.5","0.5.6","0.5.7","0.5.8","0.5.9","0.5.10","1.0.0","1.0.1","2.2.2","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","1.9.1","2.3.4","2.3.5"]]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-17-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-inspector"
```

Comment: Could you please provide the entire log content? `node-inspector` itself doesn't seem to depend on `connect` (and it shouldn't).

Comment: @ penartur I edited the post and attached full logs

Comment: And what are the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` in your `package.json`? (It would be useful to see the entire `package.json` if it doesn't contain any confidential information).

Comment: Here's my package.json file for connect -> http://pastebin.com/EZ3K7xTq

Comment: I meant *your* package.json, not connect's. Or maybe I misinterpreted you: how do you install the packages, do you install these globally or for some project?

Comment: I tried to install globally not project specific. The same error as discussed here - https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/issues/113

Comment: I should have noticed it before. I guess you're on node v0.8? It seems that versions of connect that satisfy the condition are only compatible with `{"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"}`.

The other question is why it tries to install connect in the first place. I cannot find how `node-inspector` relies on it. Can you try `npm install socket.io@"~0.8.2"` and `npm install paperboy@"~0.0.2"`?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error while using nodejsV0.8.0 in Win7.

**I fixed it when i use V0.8.1,you can try it:** http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.1/